# How set opacity to GtkWindow inside GtkEventBox

Tags: c, gtk

I want to set opacity of GtkWindow inside GtkEventBox.

```
gtk_event_box_set_visible_window(GTK_EVENT_BOX(eventbox), TRUE);
gtk_window_set_opacity(event_top->window, 1);
```

I am getting Following Error:

```
enter code here`Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_set_opacity: assertion `GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)'failed
```

Am i doing it write way?

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered to another question, the `window` member in GTK+ widgets is not a GtkWindow, but a GdkWindow.

I guess you could try the `gdk_window_set_opacity()` function in the GDK API.